# Swapping variables in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java

I was recently asked a question that stumped me.

```
public void swapEngine(Car a, Car b) {
  Engine temp = a.engine;
  a.engine = b.engine;
  b.engine = temp;
}
```

This is not a thread-safe method.  If Thread 1 calls `swapEngine(car1, car2)` and then Thread 2 calls `swapEngine(car1, car3)`, it is possible for `car2` to end up with the engine of `car3`. The most obvious way to fix this problem is to `synchronize` the method.

Synchronizing the method introduces a potential inefficiency.  What if Thread 1 calls `swapEngine(car1, car2)` and Thread 2 calls `swapEngine(car3, car4)`?  In no way can these two threads interfere with each other.  In this case the ideal situation would be for the two threads to swap the engines in parallel.  Synchronizing the method precludes this from happening.

Is there another technique to swap these engines in a thread-safe manner while still taking advantage of parallelism?

Edit: Made method public.

Comment: Well, you could add Lock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) to Car instances. Then, you could lock only those instances participating in swapping.

Comment: @mkrakhin That would be deadlock prone in a `swap(a, b); swap(b, a);` situation.

Comment: @maba, in that case the same car cannot be in two shops :)

Comment: I think the method should be part of the car abstraction itself like 
`void swapEngine(Car otherCar){ this.engine = otherCar.engine}`.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, but OP could use `tryLock()`. Then, he could return from swapEngine boolean notifying about fail or success during attempt to acquire lock, and put swapEngine() in a `while` loop.

Comment: Honestly, there is no requirement that this method is not thread safe.  It is package-private and therefore not part of an exported API.  If Cars a and b have a thread safety policy of mutual thread confinement, then this method is perfectly thread safe.

Comment: @scottb, good point.  In my haste to type the question I did not pay attention to that fact.  I will edit it to make my original intention more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments say, you can lock the cars themselves. This, however could cause a deadlock if cars are not always locked in the same order.

So, if cars have a unique identifier, you can simply sort the cars, and then swap:

```
void swapEngine(Car a, Car b) {
    Comparator<Car> byId = Comparator.comparing(Car::id);
    Car[] cars = new Car[] {a, b};
    Arrays.sort(cars, byId);
    doSwap(cars[0]), cars[1];
}

private void doSwap(Car a, Car b) { 
    synchronized(a) {
        synchronized(b) {
            Engine temp = a.engine;
            a.engine = b.engine;
            b.engine = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If the cars don't have any unique ID allowing to compare them, you can sort them by their identity hashCode (obtained using `System.identityHashCode(car)`). This hashCode, unless you have a huge memory, an enormous amount of cars, and bad luck, is unique. If you really fear such a situation, then Guava has an [arbitrary ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary%28%29) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you store `Car.engine` in [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html), you could swap them using the CAS operations:

```
public <T> void atomicSwap(AtomicReference<T> a, AtomicReference<T> b) {
    for(;;) {
        T aa = a.getAndSet(null);
        if (aa != null) {
            T bb = b.getAndSet(null);  
            if (bb != null) {
                // this piece will be reached ONLY if BOTH `a` and `b` 
                // contained non-null (and now contain null)
                a.set(bb);
                b.set(aa);
                return;
            } else {
                // if `b` contained null, try to restore old value of `a`
                // to avoid deadlocking
                a.compareAndSet(null, aa);
            }
        } 
    }          
}
```

Advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require right object ordering and don't use intrinsic locks. It also doesn't need to lock on full object--other properties can be manipulated in parallel.

Disadvantage is that now `null` values are illegal: they mean that operation on variable is in progress. You'll need to check for `null` when getting values and setting them anywhere but in constructor:

```
public <T> T getValue(AtomicReference<T> a) {
    for(;;) {
        T v = a.get();
        if (v != null)
            return v;
    }
}

public <T> T setValue(AtomicReference<T> a, T value) {
    for(;;) {
        T old = a.get();
        if (old != null && a.compareAndSet(old, value))
            return old; 
    }
}
```